# How To Launch Steam Games from Terminal?

Tags: terminal, games, steam

Is there a way to open Steam games directly from Terminal?

Answer (score 2):

## To Run on Mac Location:

```
ll /Users/YOUR_USER_PROFILE/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/steamapps/common/
```

## Command to start a game app directly:

```
open -Fa /Users/YOUR_USER_PROFILE/Library/Application\ Support/Steam/steamapps/common/Realm\ Grinder/RealmGrinderDesktop.app/Contents/MacOS/RealmGrinderDesktop
```

### Details

`man open`

> **-F**  Opens the application "fresh," that is, without
>            restoring windows. Saved persistent state is
>            lost, except for Untitled documents.
>
> **-a** application
>            Specifies the application to use for opening the
>            file

## How To Find Your (Game) Path:

Note: * lines are hyperlinks to images.

1. Open the `Steam App`
2. [Navigate to `Library` *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pN8Io.png)
3. `Right Click` on your game.
4. Open Properties
5. [Navigate to the 3rd Tab `Local Files` *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nulgE.png)
6. Select `Browse Local Files`
7. `Right Click` on the `GameName.App`
8. [Select `Get Info` *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Teeu9.png)
9. `Left Click & Drag` on the Where
10. [`Right Click` and select `Copy` *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jOrB.png)
11. `Open` your text editor and `Paste`

That will give you the path.

1. Open `Terminal`
2. Add `open -Fa` ToYourCopiedPath
3. Press Return/Enter
4. Your app will launch.

Comment: Opening games directly from the exe will not include things like launch options for the game which can make it not run correctly when launching directly from the exe. You can use the [steam browser protocol](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) to launch steam games by linking to the path of your steam.exe and the url to launch the game. E.g. (windows) `C:\Program Files\Steam\steam.exe steam://run/70`